# Did I understand correctly the point of Scott Meyers' example of std::weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, weak-ptr, effective-c++

**Effective Modern C++** (page 136) uses the following example to motivate `std::weak_ptr`. A cache is defined as an unordered map with weak pointers to objects as values. Whenever clients of this cache request an object (by key), the corresponding weak pointer is looked up and `lock()` is invoked on it. If the resulting `std::shared_ptr` is not `null`, it is returned. Otherwise, the object is re-loaded from an external database, entered into the cache and `std::shared_ptr` to it is returned.

Now the question: one might think that it would be possible to implement this without `std::weak_ptr`, but to store strong shared pointers as cache values instead. If `use_count()` of a strong pointer is equal to one, that means that all the client's pointers have been destroyed. Is the whole point of this example that using `std::weak_ptr` allows us to save memory by actually deleting the objects?

Comment: `use_count` will never be one: when you insert the new object, you have one copy in the cache and one being returned, so the use count is two. Who will ever go back and sweep the cache?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think that you are talking about two different things. First, the count will become one again when the user calls `reset()` on his copy. When he goes ahead and requests the object from the cache again, `use_count()` will be one. Second, no one will go and sweep the cash, which means that the actual object will not be deleted. But this just means that you are answering yes to my question, correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Is the whole point of this example that using std::weak_ptr allows us to save memory by actually deleting the objects?"*

Yes. Otherwise, the cache would keep the pointed-to resources allocated indefinitely. The space required for a control block, if allocated separately, is generally much less than the sort of resource that might require caching (e.g. textures, mesh data, even localized strings).

While it is possible to implement the same functionality using atomics and checking for a reference count of 1, this would require a custom handle implementation. `std::weak_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` make the whole thing much less of an ordeal to prototype.

Comment: A pop-up appeared saying that I can mark this answer as accepted, but I can't locate the button to do it...

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg An outlined checkmark should appear if you hover over the area under the vote counter.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `weak_ptr::lock()` is an atomic operation, but checking `use_count() == 1` and then acting on that information is not atomic.  For example after checking that `use_count() == 1` in the cache, but prior to deleting the data, another thread may inspect the cache and say: I want a reference to that data! Thus bumping the `use_count()` to 2.  The first thread then needlessly removes the `shared_ptr` from the cache.  This scenario can't happen with `weak_ptr`s and `weak_ptr::lock()`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yep. This is why things like `use_count` are really just debugging aids. The only way to implement the atomic check I mentioned would be in a CAS loop that, when contention is detected, would break and then lock the entire table to verify the reference update (or, if its a B-tree, just that leaf). Other strategies include strictly delay-loaded resources, which reduces contention at query sites while also spreading it all over the place wherever resources are first used.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Ah, this is another point I do not understand. How does atomicity of `lock()` help? Another thread may cause the counter to increase before we act based on the `null` returned by `lock()`...

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg If `lock` returns null, then the object would have been deleted already, so there's no way another thread could "cause the counter to increase".